# How to set default strategy for a router in akka using configuration

Tags: scala, akka

How can I use akka configuration to set default supervision strategy for a router ?

is this valid ?

```
 actor {
    deployment {
      default {
        supervisor-strategy = "akka.actor.DefaultSupervisorStrategy"
      }
      /my-router {
        router = balancing-pool        
        nr-of-instances = 3
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a while, I am surprised to say that I don't think it's possible to do that.

If you look at the [reference.conf](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html) , you realize that there is no such a property, if not for the guardian (/user).

I fear you are going to have to do it programmatically as stated [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html).

Your configuration is valid, but that property (supervisor-strategy), while accessible from code, would simply be ignored by akka.

I would be happy to be proven wrong by someone on this one.

Answer (score 0):

As @Diego Martinoia say in current version of akka don't seem to be possible to set the supervision strategy by configuration in a router, but you can mix the configuration of the router and define the strategy programmatically, a java example is:

```
final SupervisorStrategy strategy = new OneForOneStrategy(10, Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES),
Collections.<Class<? extends Throwable>>singletonList(Exception.class));

ActorRef router =  system.actorOf(ApiAiActor.props(Http.get(system)).withRouter(FromConfig.getInstance()
.withSupervisorStrategy(strategy)),"router");
```

In config you can have something like:

```
   akka {      
       actor.deployment {
          /router {
            router = round-robin-pool
            nr-of-instances = 5
          }
        }
    }
```